# Embedding Custom Fonts into HTML Pages, and require auto-download of the font from server

Tags: html, fonts

Is it possible to embed a custom font into an HTML document and force the client's end to auto-download the font file in any web browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to force the user to download the font however you can embed the font as *ask* the user to download it. I wouldn't recomend that way though becuse it's generally ill-advised for the consumer of a site to go downloading fonts, and to be honest, it's quite annoying.

However, to offer you something of more value, services such as [TypeKit](http://typekit.com/) provide a nice and clean way of embedding fonts directly into your site without the user needing or being prompted to do anything.

I've used TypeKit a few times myself and they've been pretty decent. There's other services out there to that do the same thing also so a bit of research to find the right one for you might be in order.

Comment: Assuming that the site has the font file stored on it, how can I embed the font and ask the user to download it?